# PHP Check if RTSP is working

Tags: php, rtsp

I want to check if RTSP url is working or not using PHP.

```
$url = "rtsp://somedomain.com/streamingdir";
if(is_working($url)){
echo "works!";
}else{
echo "fallen...";
}
```

**is_working** doesn't exists, i'm asking for this function, thanks

Comment: Where did you get `is_working` function?

Comment: jajaj...it doesn't exist! I need a function like that!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use a php socket client to connect to the RTSP server and then call rtsp describe method. If you get a response like "RTSP/1.0 200 OK", everything is running fine.

```
function is_working($url){
    $urlparsed = parse_url($url);
    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    if($socket == FALSE) return false;
    if(@socket_connect($socket, $urlparsed['host'], $urlparsed['port'])){
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "DESCRIBE {$url} RTSP/1.0";
        $headers[] = "User-Agent: WMPlayer/12.00.7600.16385 guid/3300AD50-2C39-46C0-AE0A-39E48EB3C868";
        $headers[] = "Accept: application/sdp";
        $headers[] = "Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0.1";
        $headers[] = "X-Accept-Authentication: Negotiate, NTLM, Digest";
        $headers[] = "Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.1";
        $headers[] = "CSeq: 1";
        $headerString = implode("\r\n", $headers) . "\r\n\r\n";
        if(false === socket_write($socket, $headerString, strlen($headerString))){
            socket_close($socket);
            return false;
        }else{
            $response = '';
            if(false === socket_recv($socket, $response, 2048,MSG_PEEK)){
                socket_close($socket);
                return false;
            }else{
                //var_dump($response);
                if(strpos($response,"RTSP/1.0 200 OK") !== FALSE){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
                socket_close($socket);
            }
        }

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

is_working("rtsp://your-url.com:1935/test.sdp");
```

Use the line "var_dump($response);" to visualize the RTSP response. Hope it helps.

Comment: I am getting this response:
RTSP/1.0 401 Unauthorized CSeq: 1 WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="a026a9464d603e2158fc6adc", nonce="16221022f", algorithm="MD5" WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="/"
even though i am giving username and password in url like this: rtsp://username:password@ip:port/ch1/main/av_stream